# Uniform integrability of martingales arising from asymmetric random walks

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

Consider a simple random walk $(X_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ on $\Bbb Z$ with transition probabilities $p_{i,i+1}=p=1-p_{i,i-1}$ for all $i$ and $1/2<p<1$. In this question ([What are some martingales for asymmetric random walks?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76486/what-are-some-martingales-for-asymmetric-random-walks)), it is shown how martingales involving powers of $X_n$ may be obtained.

Consider as an example the martingale $Y_n:=(X_n-(2p-1)n)^2-4p(1-p)n$. Suppose $X_0=0$ and let $\tau$ be the first hitting time of $1$.

**Question** How can we show that the stopped martingale $Y_{\tau\wedge n}$ is uniformly integrable (UI)?

More generally, I would like to show that stopped martingales involving higher powers of $X_n$ are also UI. The motivation for this is that we can then use the optional sampling theorem to compute the moments of $\tau$.

From general Markov chain theory $\Bbb E[\tau]<\infty$, so the only difficulty is showing that the first term of $Y_{\tau\wedge n}$, viz. $(X_{\tau\wedge n}-(2p-1)(\tau\wedge n))^2$ is UI. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: This might be overkill, but Cramer's theorem for large deviations implies that $P(\tau>n)$ decays exponentially fast in $n$, from which you can conclude two things: firstly that $E[e^{\alpha \tau}]< \infty$ for small enough $\alpha>0$, and secondly that $\sup_n E[|X_{\tau \wedge n}|^p]<\infty$, for all $p>0$. These two facts are enough to show what you want, even for the higher powers.

Comment: @Shalop Thanks for the nice idea. However I would prefer a more direct approach if possible.